# Sectioning off code with comment blocks for readability. Good or bad idea?

Tags: comments, readability, code-readability

So I recently started programming and sometimes I feel to need to separate my code with comment blocks like this:

```
//===============================================================================
//Constructors
//===============================================================================

*constructors*

//===============================================================================
//End of Constructors
//===============================================================================
```

For example, I might have a "Constructor" section and a "Getter/Setter" section, or a "Ok Button Implementation" section with all of OK Button's configuration, click listeners etc. This allows me to quickly scroll through a giant list of code but still be able to quickly tell that "this entire block of code are constructors" without actually looking at the code/comments of each method.

I know there is also code folding which I actually use in conjunction with comment blocks (I surround the comment blocks with a custom folding region). The reason I do that is because Code Folding is great when all code is folded, but when code is expanded, they don't stand out like a giant comment block can. So I use one to cover the case when all my code is minimized and the other to cover the case when all my code is expanded.

However, this is not a practice that I see used much so I am wondering if it is considered bad coding practice or something. I mean, this definitely helps the readability of my code to ME, but I also wouldn't want prospective employers to dock points for a weird coding style.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a practice being used in coding languages like for JAVA you may see as follows:

```
/**
   Author : Gary
   Method : testMethod
   Parameters : param1, param2
   Exception : ArrayOutOfBound, Exception
   Description : It is a dummy method
*/
public void dummyMethod(int param1, double param2) {
    //Sample Method Body;
    String abc = callDummyMethod();
}
```

You can add on your part to the existing practice to enhance it even more for yourself, and it shall also be the ease to other programmers if you find need for your code to be reviewed/debugged by them.

**PS**: ***Single Line comments(//) are never encouraged in this form.***

Comment: Well yes, I document/comment my methods/code as well. I use comment blocks mostly to break off lines and lines of code and/or methods into sections.